# SQL Server - Missing records in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, rows

I'm trying to accomplish the following using the below query:

- Take all records from the `Dial` table and group based on various criteria contained within the table
- Join the table to the `History` table on a unique key (`Dial.UID` and `History.UID`) to return some information unobtainable from the `Dial` table

All is working fine, apart from it is not returning rows from the `Dial` table that have a UID of 0 (this is updated in both tables once the record has been processed, but if it hasn't been processed, it remains at 0). I would like the count of all records that have a UID of 0 to be added to the Total Avail. and Total Eligible columns, based on Dial.ID

Can anyone help?

Regards

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN History.ID = 824 or Project.Name LIKE 'Example1%' or Project.Name LIKE 'Example2' or Project.Name like '%Example3%' 
          THEN 'Team One'
        WHEN History.ID = 814 OR Project.Name LIKE '%Example4%' 
          THEN 'Team Two' 
        ELSE 'Other' 
     END) as [Team],
     Project.Name as [Project],
     COUNT(Dial.ID) as [Total Avail.],
     COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN Dial.Flag = '1' AND Dial.Att = 0 OR Dial.Att > 0 AND Dial.Flag = 0 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE NULL 
            END) AS [Total Eligible],
     ISNULL(SUM(History.Attempt), 0) AS [Total Attempts],
     ROUND(COUNT(CAST(ISNULL(History.Attempt, 0) AS float)) / COUNT(CASE WHEN Dial.Flag = '1' OR Dial.Attempts > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END), 2)*100 AS [Penetration %],
     COUNT(History.Attempt) as [Unique Attempts], 
     COUNT (CASE WHEN History.Code IN ('EX1','EX2','EX3','EX4','EX5') 
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Contacts],
     COUNT (CASE WHEN History.Code IN ('EX6','EX6','EX7') 
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  AS [Success]
FROM 
     Dial Dial
LEFT JOIN 
     History History ON Dial.UID = History.UID
LEFT JOIN 
     Project Project ON Dial.ID = Project.ID
WHERE 
     Dial.Field2 NOT LIKE ''
     AND Dial.ID NOT LIKE '-%'
     AND History.DateTime > CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(8), getdate(), 112))
GROUP BY 
     Project.Name, History.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the `from` and `where` parts of your query:

```
FROM Dial Dial LEFT JOIN
     History History
     ON Dial.UID = History.UID LEFT JOIN
     Project Project
     ON Dial.ID = Project.ID
WHERE Dial.Field2 NOT LIKE '' AND
      Dial.ID NOT LIKE '-%' AND
      History.DateTime > CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),getdate(),112))
```

Your use of `left join` is correct, in the sense that you want to keep everything in the `Dial` table.  However, you undo the `left join` with the last comparison on `History.DateTime`.  It will be NULL when there is no matching record.  And NULL will fail the comparison.  You can fix this by adding a `coalesce()` or `is null` to the `where` clause.

Another fix is to add the logic to the `on` clause:

```
FROM Dial Dial LEFT JOIN
     History History
     ON Dial.UID = History.UID and
        History.DateTime > CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),getdate(),112)) LEFT JOIN
     Project Project
     ON Dial.ID = Project.ID
WHERE Dial.Field2 NOT LIKE '' AND
      Dial.ID NOT LIKE '-%'
```

If you are using a more recent version of SQL Server, you can do the date comparison by converting to a `date`:

```
FROM Dial Dial LEFT JOIN
     History History
     ON Dial.UID = History.UID and
        History.DateTime > cast(getdate() as date) LEFT JOIN
     Project Project
     ON Dial.ID = Project.ID
WHERE Dial.Field2 NOT LIKE '' AND
      Dial.ID NOT LIKE '-%'
```

It makes the query easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Line `History.DateTime > CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),getdate(),112))` in `WHERE` "turns" `LEFT JOIN History` into inner join, so resultset doesn't contain records that don't have corresponding entries in `History` table. Move it to join condition :

```
LEFT JOIN History History ON (Dial.UID = History.UID 
 AND History.DateTime > CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),getdate(),112)))
```

Comment: This answer also worked! I voted the other one as it's more detailed. Thanks for your help, though.